# Does this make sense - function?

Tags: php, smarty

```
function recurCalc($price){
  $data = array();
  $data['recurafter'] = $price * 0.3;
  $data['recurtrial'] = $price - ($recurafter*2);
  return $data;
}
$data = recurCalc($product_price);
view()->assign("price",$product_price);
view()->assign("recurtrial" $data['recurtrial']);     
view()->assign("recurafter", $data['recurafter']);
```

I am trying to make this function work, but it give me problem:

```
view()->assign("recurtrial" $data['recurtrial']);  --> view()->assign("recurtrial" $data['recurtrial']);
```

I am not particularly good at array. It was placed in index.php while smarty thing would go in html file which is rendered by pinnaclecart.

I will appreciate it if you can help.

Comment: You should never cut off error messages.

Comment: @KingCrunch, what do you mean?

Comment: You have another problem: variable `$recurafter` is unset. You probably meant `$data['recurafter']`

Comment: be careful, theres a problem here : view()->assign("recurtrial" $data['recurtrial']);  correct line is view()->assign("recurtrial", $data['recurtrial']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your obvious problem is that you're trying to return multiple values from one function. Try using a separate function for each value:

```
 function recurAfter($price) { return $price * 0.3; }
 function recurTrial($price) { return $price - recurAfter($price); }

 view()->assign("price", $product_price);
 view()->assign("recurtrial", recurTrial($product_price));
 view()->assign("recurafter", recurAfter($product_price));
```

Answer (score 3):

`array` is a keyword and cannot be used as a class(name).

```
$data = new Array();
```

What you probably want is a common array

```
$data = array()
```

Read here: http://php.net/language.types.array

Comment: @KingCrunch, so if I want to save data in array, it has to be $data = Array()? or is it $data[] = Array();? I am sorry I am confused on array

Comment: Like I wrote: `$data = array()`. With `$data[]` you _access_ the array, but for this, it must be an array before ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch, oh ok so array() stores data info while [] allows me to get data from array. got it.

Comment: With `$data[]` you are referring to a new element at the end of the (previously set) `$data` array. When you write `$data[] = Array()`, you are creating a new array (with `Array()`) and appending it at the end of `$data` (with `$data[] = ...`)

Comment: @Josephine I'm glad you got that. I wasn't sure if I was being clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `new` keyword for this situation.

Comment: You want to create an array. The correct syntax for that in php is `$data = array();`

Comment: With `new` you instanciate a new object from the given classname. An array is not an object in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to declare an array in PHP is

```
$data = array();
```

or

```
$data = array(
    'recurafter' => $price * 0.3,
    'recurtrial' =>  $price - ($recurafter*2),
);
```

I think this is better :

```
function recurCalc($price){
  $recurafter = $price * 0.3;
  $recurtrial = $price - ($recurafter*2);

  $data = array( 'recurafter'=>$recurafter, 'recurtrial'=>$recurtrial);
  return $data
};
```

Comment: ah your examples make sense and let me try it out

Comment: wait how to do function to calculate later?

Comment: thanks for the help. it still bugs me because it is done in pinnaclecart i am lost in smarty :/

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to just do

```
$data = Array();
```

As for the function... hard to tell how much sense it makes out of context, but it will work.

Comment: No it won't, because `$price - ($recurafter*2);
` makes a reference to an unset `$recurafter` variable.

Comment: @Zecc quite so - $data['recurtrial'] = $price - ($data['recurafter']*2) - this will teach me to answer questions before I have my morning coffee :)